# InnerHTML has not accepted HTML String

Tags: javascript, html

HTML displays string format thank showing it as HTML. I copied innerHTML with dynamic HTML from string.

```
document.getElementById("tableReplicateGridTemplate").innerHTML = '@Model.sGridTemplate';
```

My output in HTML page is shown in string and not converted to HTML

[image: Click Here For Output]

Comment: What is rendered on the page source?

Comment: Something this way .var sHTML='                 &lt;tr id=&quot;trReplicateGridTemplate&quot;&gt;                     &lt;td id=&quot;tdReplicateGri

Comment: var sHTML='                 &lt;tr id=&quot;trReplicateGridTemplate&quot;&gt;                     &lt;td id=&quot;tdReplicateGri

Comment: There are no tags in your HTML string, you've to modify `@Model.sGridTemplate`.

Comment: Can you add a sample html which you are trying to add?

Comment: U mean, Change to HTML tags?

Comment: ok I will replace "&lt;" by "<" etc and try

Comment: Im actually copying the HTMl from template file from C# and sending it via vies to cshtml file. When it reaches cshtml, it is converted to this format with "&lt;" etc

Comment: That's the code which should actually be fixed then.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: Im using javascript, jquery

Comment: Are you using JSON? You can convert that on receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for reply.
Finally with your help, I edited my code as below and it worked.

```
var sHTML = '@Model.sGridTemplate';
                       sHTML = sHTML.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
                       sHTML = sHTML.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
                       sHTML = sHTML.replace(/&quot;/g, "\"");
                       sHTML = sHTML.replace(/&#10;/g, "");
                       sHTML = sHTML.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType` to your ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'url',
  dataType : 'html' // this line will convert the data sent to html
});
```